# WCF Peer to Peer, Are There Nodes Out There?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am using WCF in .NET 3.5 to implement a peer to peer networking application. To resolve peer nodes I am using PNRP.

IGlobalStoreServiceContract is my contract as shown below,

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://GlobalStoreEventDriven.API", CallbackContract = typeof(IGlobalStoreServiceContract))]
internal interface IGlobalStoreServiceContract
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void NotifyGlobalStoreDataInserted(string globalGroup, DateTime maxDateTime);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]   
    void RegisterNode();

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void SynchronizeMemberList(Guid clientId);
}
```

I am using some code like this to join each node to the peer to peer network.

```
DuplexChannelFactory<IGlobalStoreChannel> channelFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IGlobalStoreChannel>(instance, "GlobalStoreAPIEndPoint");
IGlobalStoreChannel globalStoreChannel = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

globalStoreChannel.Open();
```

My question is as soon as I have opened the channel how can I best tell if other peer nodes are on the network?

For instance I could call one of the methods in my contract RegisterNode, and each node in the network could use a callback to call SynchronizeMemberList. I would then know whether other nodes were there.

The trouble with that is it is all asynchronous. If I call RegisterNode and no one replies, it doesn't really mean no one is there, it could just mean that I didn't wait long enough.

What do you reckon? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Peer-to-Peer Programming with WCF and .NET Framework 3.5: Peer Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc297274.aspx#WCFP2P_topic7) by Amit Bahree and Chris Peiris:

> The final logical step after creating
>   and publishing a peer is resolving a
>   peer. What good is it to publish
>   something to the cloud if another peer
>   cannot find you? We use the
>   `PeerNameResolver` class to resolve for
>   a specific peer in a given cloud. The
>   `PeerNameResolver` can resolve a peer to
>   either a `PeerRecord` or a cloud,
>   depending on the parameters that are
>   passed. The resolution process
>   finishes either when the maximum
>   number of record entries for the
>   `PeerRecordCollection` is reached or
>   when it has reached the end of various
>   clouds.
>
> The `PeerNameResolver` class exposes an overloaded method that is called `Resolve` and is used to resolve a given peer synchronously.
>
> Listing 17 shows us how to try to resolve for a peer that is called `MySecurePeer`. The Resolve method returns a collection of type `PeerNameRecordCollection` through which we iterate. Listing 18 shows the result of this when running on a computer that has three network cards.

```
PeerName myPeer = new PeerName("MySecurePeer", PeerNameType.Secured);
PeerNameResolver resolver = new PeerNameResolver();

PeerNameRecordCollection results = resolver.Resolve(myPeer);

Console.WriteLine("{0} Peers Found:", results.Count.ToString());
int i = 1;

foreach (PeerNameRecord peer in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} Peer:{1}", i++, peer.PeerName.ToString());
    foreach (IPEndPoint ip in peer.EndPointCollection)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t Endpoint: {0}", ip.ToString());
    }
}
```

So, I guess you should check out [`PeerNameResolver.Resolve` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.peertopeer.peernameresolver.resolve.aspx):

> This method associates peer names to
>   clouds. Calling the `PeerNameResolver`
>   method is similar to calling the
>   `Resolve` method for each peer name
>   record in the
>   `PeerNameRecordCollection`. Note that
>   using the `Resolve` method on an
>   individual peer name record does not
>   invalidate resolving multiple peer
>   names.
>
> For every `Resolve` method, there is an
>   equivalent `ResolveAsync` method. They
>   are identical in the parameters they
>   are passed, except that the
>   `ResolveAsync` method includes a system
>   token in its parameter list for
>   asynchronous event handling.